# Can I change the commit history in two ways using Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, commit, git-commit

I'm asking this question because I'm studying the **Pro Git** book and there is a chapter, **Rewriting History**, that explains how to change the last commit *$ git commit --amend*, change multiple commit messages *$ git rebase -i HEAD~3*, delete a particular file or folder in all the commits with *$ git filter-branch --tree-filter*.

**Here my question**: the book doesn't mention the possibility of doing this work by multiple checkouts along ALL the commit's history. So I move my HEAD, commit by commit, and I change this particular commit with *$ git commit --amend* one by one.

I know it's really (REALLY!) expensive in terms of time spent, but is it really possibile (i.e. it works)?
And if yes, in which cases this could be useful?

Comment: Note that you're not in a technical sense *changing* any of the commits. You are instead making *new and supposedly improved* commits, then switching from using the old (and terrible?) to the new (and improved?) commits. The hash IDs of the new commits differ from the old ones, and if you use the old hash IDs, you can see that the old commits still exist.

Comment: Besides VonC's link to the newfangled `git filter-repo`, the old (nominally deprecated) `git filter-branch` does the same thing. We just use `git rev-list` or similar to enumerate all the raw hash IDs of all the commits to copy, then start copying away. When we're done, we switch any names that used to refer to the old commits over, so that they refer to the new improved ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *all* commits, you can use [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which can rewrite anything you need (author, commit message, files or file contents, ...)

For example, regarding commit message, [using message-callback](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS):

> The message callback is quite similar to the previous three callbacks, though it operates on a bytestring that is likely more than one line:
>
> ```sh
> git-filter-repo --message-callback '
>  if b"Signed-off-by:" not in message:
>    message += b"\nSigned-off-by: Me My <self@and.eye>"
>  return re.sub(b"[Ee]-?[Mm][Aa][Ii][Ll]", b"email", message)'
> ```

Comment: In other words, `git-filter-repo` should be used instead of `git filter-branch` in order to obtain the same result. However I can't understand if  I could use the naive "I manually change all the commits, one by one, using the `$ git commit --amend`".

Comment: @Filippo Yes, git filter-branch is obsolete. And you can use the commit amend approach, but it does not easily scale when you have hundreds of commits to change.

Comment: Thank you, I needed confirmation on this.